# Consuming the results produced by an ExecutorService. Which class?

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice

I wish I would have written the class/interface name down but I didn't...

When looking through the JDK javadocs I saw reference to a class/interface with the purpose of collecting and consuming the results produced by an `ExecutorService` (completed `Futures<T>`s), possibly elsewhere in the system. At the time I took a mental note of it because it was a perfect fit for what I needed, but I can't seem to get the name of the class off the tip of my tongue.

Anyone have an idea of what I am referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you referring to [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) ?